# Is ElasticSearch watch able to write data to Mysql

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some meta data in ElasticSearch, when the meta data updated I need to sync the updates to Mysql. So I'm wondering that is there an ES Watch/Triger could do this automatically please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct action in watcher calling mysql ( that I know of ).

But you could create a simple API called by watcher that would update your database on a `Webhook Action`

Comment: Thanks, which ES watcher could watch a specific Index/Type data updates please.

Comment: Or say is possible for me to monitor and get the updates of index by Watcher please?

Comment: By watcher , you mean the watcher plugin from Elastic, right ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html